# kafka jdbc source connector error in query mode

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka

I have a JDBCSourceConnector in kafka that uses a query to stream data from database. 
but I have problem with the query I wrote for selecting data.

I tested query in Postgres psql and also in DBeaver. It's working fine but in kafka config, it produces an SQL syntax error

**Error**

> ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{name='null', query='select "Users".* from "Users" join "SchoolUserPivots" on "Users".id = "SchoolUserPivots".user_id where school_id = 1 and role_id = 2', topicPrefix='teacher', timestampColumn='"Users".updatedAt', incrementingColumn='id'}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:221)
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

**Config json**

```
 {
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "timestamp.column.name": "\"Users\".updatedAt",
  "incrementing.column.name": "id",
  "connection.password": "123",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "query": "select \"Users\".* from \"Users\" join \"SchoolUserPivots\" on \"Users\".id = \"SchoolUserPivots\".user_id where school_id = 1 and role_id = 2",
  "timestamp.delay.interval.ms": "5000",
  "mode": "timestamp+incrementing",
  "topic.prefix": "teacher",
  "connection.user": "user",
  "name": "SourceTeacher",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/school",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the column names : `where school_id = 1 and role_id = 2`  (instead of `'shool_id'`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name same error, no difference

Comment: Update your question with your fixed code and the new error. My guess is that maybe you fixed `school_id`, but didn't apply that fix to `role_id`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel code & error updated

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything obviously wrong in that query.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel actuality the problem is that everything is Ok

Comment: Could you try changing it to `select * from (<your original query) a`. I guess that Kafka is adding its own where-clause.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yesss, Its like working

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `"mode": "timestamp+incrementing",` with a custom `query` that includes `WHERE`.

See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector for more details, as well as https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/566. That github issue suggests one workaround, by using a subselect for your query.